# Get last 3 month data without any date column in table

Tags: sql, oracle

is there a way to fetch last 3 months data in a table if there is no date column present in table. Does Oracle db maintain some sort of internal column that maintains order in which data is entered in table.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of doable. In oracle, there is a virtual column called `ORA_ROWSCN`. Which holds the version of the row. It is updated with the row itself (So It doesn't keep the insert order). Basically, it's a timestamp and it can be converted to a timestamp with the help `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` function. [Document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions142.htm)

Need to mention that `ORA_ROWSCN` by default works on the block level. So all the rows in the same block will have the same SCN. Unless you create your table with `ROWDEPENDENCIES`. [Document](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns007.htm#SQLRF50953)

Comment: I tried running above, but found below error - ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1
08181. 00000 -  "specified number is not a valid system change number"
*Cause:    supplied scn was beyond the bounds of a valid scn.
*Action:   use a valid scn.

Comment: when i do SELECT SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) FROM table, it does gave result though

Answer (score 1):

If you have flashback enabled (with a large enough retention period) then you can get all the new rows and changed rows using:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name
MINUS
SELECT * FROM table_name AS OF TIMESTAMP ( ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3) );
```

Comment: I got below error while running the above query - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: @NarendraPandey It works for me [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5d02c2b438ed969e5b9f0097cd489cc2) (with a shorter timescale). If you have a `CLOB` column and it is causing an issue then don't use `SELECT *` and use `SELECT col1, col2, col3` and exclude the `CLOB` column otherwise, you can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between the two tables and filter on rows where the joined flashback query does not match.